# Converting cartesian coordinates to latitude/longitude in Geographical Data

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, gis, sql-server-2012

I have a database, which uses the **GGRS87** reference system, and contains x-y coordinates of objects. I need to convert them to lat/lon, so that I can store them in SQL Server 2012 using Geography data type.

Or is there a way I can use those x-y coordinates directly to create a geography data? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xy value directly to create the geometry objects, as long as you know the SRID code for the GGRS87 co-ordinate system (I think it's 4121).

Then use the [STGeomFromText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx) method to create your features. E.g.

```
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(122 47)', 4121));
```